# Происхождение названия города Харькова

Tags: топонимика

От какого слова происходит названия города Харькова?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть множество версий, вот две из них:

*1. по названию реки Харьков, на которой стоит город.

 2. от имени дочери Аттилы - Харьхе (в переводе Лебедь).*